# Convert elasticsearch bool query into Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, java-8, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
GET feeds/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comment",
            "query": { 
              "match": {
                "comment.c_text": "This is mateen"
              }
            },"inner_hits": {}
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "title": {
              "value": "This is mateen"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "body": {
              "value": "This is mateen"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my mappings

```
PUT feeds 
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties":{
      "comment":{
        "type":nested
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am new to Elasticsearch, I get my desired result in kibana now I want to use this query in my Java application as I want to use this bool search query into my spring-boot application.

Can anyone tell me how to convert this query into Java?

Comment: what is version of elasticsearch and elasticsearch java client ?

Comment: elasticsearch 7.17.3  @SagarPatel

Comment: You can use rest client as rest high level client is deprecated.

Comment: i have seen the documentation it says rest client is deprecated in favour of java api client can you guide me further- @SagarPatel

Comment: Yes, its means Java high level client is deprecated and you can use Java API Client for which i have posted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Java Rest client with ES 7.17.3 version using below dependancy

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
     <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
     <version>7.17.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is Java code:

```java
Query bodyTermQuery = TermQuery.of(tq -> tq.field("body").value("hey"))._toQuery();
Query titleTermQuery = TermQuery.of(tq -> tq.field("title").value("hey"))._toQuery();

Query matchQuery = MatchQuery.of(mq -> mq.field("comment.c_text").query("hey"))._toQuery();

Query nestedQuery = NestedQuery.of(nq -> nq.path("comment").query(matchQuery)
                .innerHits(ih -> ih.highlight(h -> h.requireFieldMatch(true)).fields("comment.c_text")))._toQuery();

SearchResponse<Object> response = client.search(
                s -> s.index("feeds").query(q -> q.bool(b -> b.should(nestedQuery, titleTermQuery, bodyTermQuery))),
                Object.class);
```

Comment: this one is showing me the error `co.elastic.clients.util.MissingRequiredPropertyException: Missing required property 'Highlight.fields'` can you help me out in this regard

Comment: there is issue in inner highlishts when i remove it it is hsowing me the result but without inner hits when i sued your code it showing me missing required property

Comment: it is again giving me the same error

Comment: @Ali is it working if you removed highlighting.

Comment: it is not working highlighting but if i remove nestedquery it start giving me output but not getting my desired result as i want to pop out the inner hits @Sagar

Comment: @Ali can you please update your questiona and add index mapping so will try to replicate on my local system.

Comment: i have updated it can you please check